# Is there anyway of modifying the CSS in the Webkit's CSS inspector?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Is there anyway of modifying the CSS in the Webkit's CSS inspector, and seeing the results in real time (just like Firebug)?

I'm using Google Chrome

(I tried Firebug Lite for Google Chrome but it doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just right click anywhere in Chrome and choose "Inspect Element".

You will be able to do CSS inspection and even change the styles on the fly.

[Chrome Inspect Element http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/5921/inspect.png](http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/5921/inspect.png)

Answer (score -1):

Just press **Ctrl + Shift + J** or *F12* And you will get a nice Developer Window. (Same as Daniel Vassallo shows but this is the keyboard shortcut).

Now click "Elements" or the magnifying glass and inspect elements.

[image]

Comment: This will bring up the console, not the CSS inspector.